# Chrome not recognizing USB label printer in usb-internal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, winusb, webusb

I'm trying to create a web app where I can print labels directly to a label printer Zebra LP2844 using webusb. The problem I am having is that I can't find the printer under Chrome://usb-internal. The driver used in device manager is usbprint.sys. When I change it to winusb using Zadig the printer shows up but I'm not longer able to print to it. Every time I try to print it just says error-printing. As soon as I rollback the driver it prints just fine but can not be found in chrome. I tried this in win7.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice between two drivers, `usbprint.sys` and `winusb.sys`. If you configure Windows to use the former then you get support for the printer through the Windows native printer drivers. If you configure Windows to use the latter then you can build support for the printer in JavaScript using the WebUSB API.

Can you post the code you are trying to use to print using WebUSB? Where is the "error-printing" error coming from?

Comment: After playing around a bit, I was able to get the printer to print through WebUSB API but printing from desktop applications no longer works. This is using winusb.sys driver. I'm wondering now if WebUSB API printer can be shared between desktop and web apps.